# How to get the Monitor Screen Resolution from a hWnd?

Tags: winapi, screen-resolution

How to get the monitor screen resolution from a hWnd?

I am using a hWnd because the window could be located on any one of multiple monitors.

i.e. the hWnd top/left coordinate is on a Monitor that has a Screen Resolution of 800 x 600.

I program in a language called PL/B and it allows calling Windows API.

What Window APIs can be used?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `user32` function [MonitorFromWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfromwindow) allows you to pass in an hwnd, and returns a handle to the monitor it's on (or a default - see the linked MSDN article for details). With that you can call [GetMonitorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfoa) to retrieve a [MONITORINFO struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-monitorinfo) which contains a RECT detailing its resolution.

See the [Multiple Screens Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/multiple-display-monitors-reference) section of MSDN for more details.

I'd add example code but I don't know the language you referenced, and I don't know how useful C# example code would be to you. If you think it'll help, let me know and I'll code up something real quick.

Answer (score 27):

Here's a C++ code example that works for me:

```
HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
MONITORINFO info;
info.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &info);
int monitor_width = info.rcMonitor.right - info.rcMonitor.left;
int monitor_height = info.rcMonitor.bottom - info.rcMonitor.top;
```

Answer (score 5):

There is GetSystemMetrics too, check it out on msdn

Comment: True, however using MonitorFromWindow will work better in a situation where the end user has multiple monitors.

Comment: @sidewinderguy What does RECT  rcWork; signifies in the MONITORINFO struct ? Not getting what it meant by "work area rectangle of the display monitor" on MSDN

Answer (score 4):

Here's some C# code that gets the resolution (in DPI) via P/Invoke:

```
public static void GetWindowDpi(IntPtr hwnd, out int dpiX, out int dpiY)
{
    var handle = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MonitorFlag.MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);

    GetDpiForMonitor(handle, MonitorDpiType.MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI, out dpiX, out dpiY);
}

/// <summary>
/// Determines the function's return value if the window does not intersect any display monitor.
/// </summary>
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "IdentifierTypo")]
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "UnusedMember.Local")]
private enum MonitorFlag : uint
{
    /// <summary>Returns NULL.</summary>
    MONITOR_DEFAULTTONULL = 0,
    /// <summary>Returns a handle to the primary display monitor.</summary>
    MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = 1,
    /// <summary>Returns a handle to the display monitor that is nearest to the window.</summary>
    MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = 2
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr MonitorFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, MonitorFlag flag);

[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "IdentifierTypo")]
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "UnusedMember.Local")]
private enum MonitorDpiType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The effective DPI.
    /// This value should be used when determining the correct scale factor for scaling UI elements.
    /// This incorporates the scale factor set by the user for this specific display.
    /// </summary>
    MDT_EFFECTIVE_DPI = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// The angular DPI.
    /// This DPI ensures rendering at a compliant angular resolution on the screen.
    /// This does not include the scale factor set by the user for this specific display.
    /// </summary>
    MDT_ANGULAR_DPI = 1,
    /// <summary>
    /// The raw DPI.
    /// This value is the linear DPI of the screen as measured on the screen itself.
    /// Use this value when you want to read the pixel density and not the recommended scaling setting.
    /// This does not include the scale factor set by the user for this specific display and is not guaranteed to be a supported DPI value.
    /// </summary>
    MDT_RAW_DPI = 2
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetDpiForMonitor(IntPtr hwnd, MonitorDpiType dpiType, out int dpiX, out int dpiY);
```

Comment: This no longer works on newer systems, since the GetDpiForMonitor method is supported up until Windows 8.1

Comment: @Filipsi are you sure? I was using Windows 10 when I wrote this code.

Comment: Use `[DllImport("Shcore.dll")]` to import `GetDpiForMonitor` method for Win 8.1 and upper.

Answer (score 0):

For Monitors with hight resolution 2K 4K > 1920px

```
void GetDesktopResolution(int* horizontal, int* vertical)
{

    HDC hScreenDC = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
    int width = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
    int height = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);
    ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hScreenDC);

    RECT desktop;
    const HWND hDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
    GetWindowRect(hDesktop, &desktop);
    
    if (width > 2000)
    {
        const POINT ptZero = { 0, 0 };
        HMONITOR mon = MonitorFromPoint(ptZero, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);

        DEVICE_SCALE_FACTOR f;// vers < win 8 = GetScaleFactorForDevice(DEVICE_PRIMARY);
        GetScaleFactorForMonitor(mon,&f);
        if (f > 110)
        {
            *horizontal = width * ((f+10) / 100.0);
            *vertical = height * ((f+10) / 100.0);
        }
        else
        {
            *horizontal = width;
            *vertical = height;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        *horizontal = desktop.right;
        *vertical = desktop.bottom;
    }
}
```

Comment: need to include "shellscalingapi.h"

Answer (score -2):

```
RECT windowsize;    // get the height and width of the screen
GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowsize);

int srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
int srcwidth = windowsize.right;
```

Comment: This is a window size, not screen size.