# How to get screen resolution in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, screen-resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to get the Monitor Screen Resolution from an hWnd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156212/how-to-get-the-monitor-screen-resolution-from-an-hwnd)

Is there a way to get the screen resolution in C++?
I have searched MSDN but with no luck. The closest thing I found was [`ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183413.aspx) but that doesn't seem to have a way to just return the res without changing it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156212/how-to-get-the-monitor-screen-resolution-from-an-hwnd

Comment: Ok, one of the answers to that question worked. (`GetSystemMetrics()`) Flagging as duplicate

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
#include "wtypes.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Get the horizontal and vertical screen sizes in pixel
void GetDesktopResolution(int& horizontal, int& vertical)
{
   RECT desktop;
   // Get a handle to the desktop window
   const HWND hDesktop = GetDesktopWindow();
   // Get the size of screen to the variable desktop
   GetWindowRect(hDesktop, &desktop);
   // The top left corner will have coordinates (0,0)
   // and the bottom right corner will have coordinates
   // (horizontal, vertical)
   horizontal = desktop.right;
   vertical = desktop.bottom;
}

int main()
{       
   int horizontal = 0;
   int vertical = 0;
   GetDesktopResolution(horizontal, vertical);
   cout << horizontal << '\n' << vertical << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Source: http://cppkid.wordpress.com/2009/01/07/how-to-get-the-screen-resolution-in-pixels/

Comment: Does this work with multiple monitors?

Comment: Here's how to do it with multiple monitors (in the answers): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631292/how-detect-current-screen-resolution

Comment: This will give you size of desktop **without Taskbar**

Comment: @Quest good point. I just realised that I actually do need a size without task bar :)

Comment: for 4K screen with 3840 x 2160 resolution in Windows 10, this method returns 1536 x 864. can anybody explain that?

Comment: @user2199593 It's probably due to the method, `GetDesktopWindow`; you might have a display of `1536 x 864` as your main display, even if you have a 4k display connected.

Comment: @user2199593 I'm seeing the same - it appears to be due to DPI.  See this thread on MSDN social: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e38ee167-a246-4e5f-a858-52dcb17e0e4b/getmonitorinfo-tells-app-my-4k-monitor-is-2560-x-1440?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: ... so adding `SetProcessDPIAware();` to be the very first thing done in winMain appears to fix it.

Comment: Also see some really useful stuff on EnumDisplayMonitors here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541484/enumdisplaymonitors-callback

Answer (score 1):

In Embarcadero C++ builder you can get it like this

```
Screen->Height;
Screen->Width;
```

This is specific for VCL framework which is supplied with Embarcadero products: C++ Builder, Delphi.

Comment: This answer applies to other Embarcadero compilers, like Delphi (ie. width := Screen.Width;). The OP wasn't explicit as to the targeted platform or compiler so this answer isn't wrong (that it was specific to Embarcadero was specified).

Comment: `#include <X11/Xlib.h>

Display* disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Screen*  scrn = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(disp);
int height = scrn->height;
int width  = scrn->width;` with the linker option `-lX11`.