# EnumDisplayMonitors callback

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, callback

I am trying to use the `EnumDisplayMonitors` to create a dynamic array of each monitor and store the `DISPLAY_DEVICE` structure. Why is the below code not correct?

```
BOOL CALLBACK MyInfoEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData) {

    MONITORINFOEX iMonitor;
    iMonitor.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEX);
    GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &iMonitor);

    if (iMonitor.dwFlags == DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        *reinterpret_cast<ScreenArray*>(dwData) = ScreenArray(&iMonitor);
        return true;
    };

}
```

Called using

```
ScreenArray monitorArray[15];

int i = 0;
EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, MyInfoEnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&monitorArray[i++]));
```

The first in the array (`monitorArray[0]`) returns correct information for the second monitor but `monitorArray[1]` is max values.

EDIT: Solved
The method I used was just implementing a function I created:

```
MonitorArray *mA = reinterpret_cast<MonitorArray*>(dwData);
        mA->addScreen(&iMonitor);
```

Comment: `EnumDisplayMonitors` calls `MyInfoEnumProc` multiple times, each time passing `&monitorArray[0]` in `dwData`. No other elements of the array are ever touched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback is called once for each monitor, but your callback is not incrementing through the array each time it is called. You need to do something more like this instead:

```
struct ScreenArrayInfo
{
    ScreenArray *Array;
    int Count;
    int MaxCount;
};

BOOL CALLBACK MyInfoEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    MONITORINFOEX iMonitor;
    iMonitor.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEX);
    GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &iMonitor);

    if (iMonitor.dwFlags == DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        ScreenArrayInfo *info = reinterpret_cast<ScreenArrayInfo*>(dwData);
        if (info->Count == info->MaxCount) return false;
        info->Array[info->Count] = ScreenArray(&iMonitor);
        Info->Count++;
        return true;
    };
}

ScreenArray monitorArray[15];
ScreenArrayInfo info;
info.Array = monitorArray;
info.Count = 0;
info.MaxCount = 15;

EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, &MyInfoEnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&info));
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <vector>

BOOL CALLBACK MyInfoEnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    MONITORINFOEX iMonitor;
    iMonitor.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEX);
    GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &iMonitor);

    if (iMonitor.dwFlags == DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        reinterpret_cast< std::vector<ScreenArray>* >(dwData)->push_back(ScreenArray(&iMonitor));
        return true;
    };
}

std::vector<ScreenArray> monitorArray;
EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, &MyInfoEnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&monitorArray));
```

Comment: Looking at the documentation on GetMonitorInfo, it doesn't say that dwFlags can be DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER, only MONITORINFOF_PRIMARY as a flag. Where do you see that it can be DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER?

Comment: @bpeikes I didn't get it from anywhere. It is in the OP's original code. I just maintained the OP's code but added proper array handling to it.

Answer (score 9):

`EnumDisplayMonitors` takes the parameter you pass it and calls your callback once for each monitor, passing it the same parameter every time. Your index into `monitorArray` is never incremented. Instead you need to manage the indexing within the callback itself.

Here's a little class that automatically builds a vector of all monitors in the system.

```
struct MonitorRects
{
    std::vector<RECT>   rcMonitors;

    static BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnum(HMONITOR hMon,HDC hdc,LPRECT lprcMonitor,LPARAM pData)
    {
        MonitorRects* pThis = reinterpret_cast<MonitorRects*>(pData);
        pThis->rcMonitors.push_back(*lprcMonitor);
        return TRUE;
    }

    MonitorRects()
    {
        EnumDisplayMonitors(0, 0, MonitorEnum, (LPARAM)this);
    }
};
```

Use it like this:

```
MonitorRects monitors;
cout << "You have " << monitors.rcMonitors.size() << " monitors connected.";
```

Comment: This is such a succinct way to do it, great answer :)