# Get the HMONITOR handle of the current active monitor

Tags: c++, handle, multiple-monitors

I have a multi monitor setup. Right is primary monitor, left is secondary monitor. I want to identify in which monitor,my window is invoked, so that i can create and show my window in that monitor.

I'm having problem getting the handle of the current selected monitor.

I tried using MonitorFromWindow() API, but it always gives the primary monitor handle.Hence,  my window is always showed in primary monitor irrespective of from which monitor it is invoked.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: There i sno "current" monitor, all monitors are current and active. `MonitorFromWindow` gets you handle for given window at the moment, and if you want another monitor then you need to enumerate monitors and choose the one you need there.

Comment: How will enumerate monitor help in my use case. I need to know from which monitor my window is invoked.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541484/enumdisplaymonitors-callback) on monitor enumeration (`EnumDisplayMonitors` API).

Answer (score 0):

Try MonitorFromPoint, using the cursor coordinates from GetCursorPos

Comment: What if the user just moves the mouse cursor to other monitor

Comment: Well your question is strange. I don't really understand exactly what you're doing. If your window is in the primary monitor, then of course MonitorfromWindow will give you the primary monitor. Maybe clarify your question for better answers.

Comment: My application runs in both the monitors. For Example, if the user select (File->Help)menu or press F1 key in Secondary monitor, i need to create and show my help window in secondary monitor.