# Windows Get Screen Resolution in C

Tags: c, windows, mingw, screen-resolution

Using plain C, (not C++ / C# / Objective-C) how do I get the screen resolution in Windows?

My compiler is MingW (not sure if relevant). All solutions I have found online are for C++ or some other C variant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [GetSystemMetrics()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
DWORD dwWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
DWORD dwHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use the Windows API by including `windows.h` in your code. MingW may already come with this header file.

```
#include <windows.h>

void GetMonitorResolution(int *horizontal, int *vertical) {
    *height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    *width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**FOR LINUX IF SOMEONE NEED**

I tried it on **Ubuntu 20.04** and it works perfectly !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned short *get_screen_size(void)
{
    static unsigned short size[2];
    char *array[8];
    char screen_size[64];
    char* token = NULL;

    FILE *cmd = popen("xdpyinfo | awk '/dimensions/ {print $2}'", "r");

    if (!cmd)
        return 0;

    while (fgets(screen_size, sizeof(screen_size), cmd) != NULL);
    pclose(cmd);

    token = strtok(screen_size, "x\n");

    if (!token)
        return 0;

    for (unsigned short i = 0; token != NULL; ++i) {
        array[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "x\n");
    }
    size[0] = atoi(array[0]);
    size[1] = atoi(array[1]);
    size[2] = -1;

    return size;
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned short *size = get_screen_size();

    printf("Screen resolution = %dx%d\n", size[0], size[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

If you have any question, do not hesitate ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been answered: [How to get the Monitor Screen Resolution from a hWnd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156212/how-to-get-the-monitor-screen-resolution-from-an-hwnd).

```
HMONITOR monitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
MONITORINFO info;
info.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &info);
int monitor_width = info.rcMonitor.right - info.rcMonitor.left;
int monitor_height = info.rcMonitor.bottom - info.rcMonitor.top;
```

Comment: MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST is not defined.

Comment: @Jimmay, Open up winuser.h and search for it to see if it's in there at all, possibly just hidden behind an #ifdef.